# get_absolute_url with multiple foreign key

Tags: python, django, url, django-models, foreign-keys

Hello Django Pros out there!

Is it possible to get the pk of a model, which is not the direct foreign key of the model? But the foreignkey of the foreign key model?

My Models:

```
class Patient(models.Model):
    patientID = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True, help_text='Insert PatientID')

class Examination(models.Model):
    number_of_examination = models.IntegerField(choices=EXA_Choices)
    patient = models.ForeignKey(Patient, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_of_examination = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, help_text='YYYY-MM-DD')

class AbsoluteValue(models.Model):
    examination = models.ForeignKey(Examination, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    attr1 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    attr2 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    attr3 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

and I want to define the get_absolute_url of the AbsoluteValue class. It should redirect to the Patient detail page. Due to this it needs the pk of the Patient class.

My try:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('member:detail', kwargs={'pk': self.examination__patient_id})
```

The error says that there is no URL to redirect to. So my query is not working, or I should not query in this function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want `self.examination.patient_id` instead of `self.examination__patient_id`. The double underscore notation is used by the Django ORM e.g. in `filter()`. For regular attribute access in Python, use a dot.

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('member:detail', kwargs={'pk': self.examination.patient_id})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works! Would you help me with another URL question?

Comment: Please ask a new question if you have a separate issue.